# Trigger keys programatically on website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this simple "webpage" to test out how to check if a key is pressed. It should log 1 if you press the left arrow key and 2 if you press the right arrow key:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 37 ){
            console.log(1);
        }
        if(event.keyCode == 39 ){
            console.log(2) ;
        }
    });

    $(window).trigger("keydown", { which: 37, keyCode: 37 });
</script>
```

You can test it. It works fine. However, if I want to trigger this event programmatically through Javascript I fail.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programatically) and tested all methods on it on the window, document and body DOM object and the "script" JQuery objects.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to trigger that event?

Comment: @motanelu I am inserting the code snippets from the post mentioned about into my chrome console and change the which attribute to 37. Already tried to change the attribute to "keyCode" but that neither worked out.

Comment: What do you need it for? Most browsers don't allow triggering keys for security purposes. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programatically/19883789#19883789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on preserving `window.addEventListener()`, trigger the event without jQuery. See [the MDN documentation on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 37 ){
            console.log(1);
        }
        if(event.keyCode == 39 ){
            console.log(2) ;
        }
    });

    var event = new Event("keydown");
    event.keyCode = 37; event.which = 37;
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
</script>
```